# Every edge of $K_{m,n}$ is contained in exactly one of two isomorphic subgraphs of $K_{m,n}$, iff m, n are even?

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove:

**Every edge of a bipartite complete graph $K_{m,n}$ is contained in exactly one of two isomorphic subgraphs of $K_{m,n}$ if and only if m or n is even.**

If this statement is wrong, give a counter example.

Comment: Do you see that one direction is easy?

Comment: what do you mean by one-direction? I do not understand the question "one of two isomorphic subgraphs". Km,n has more than 2 subgraphs, I am confused.

Comment: Another way to phrase the question: "We can color the edges of $K_{m,n}$ red and blue such that the red subgraph is isomorphic to the blue subgraph, if and only if $m$ or $n$ is even."

Comment: The two "directions" of this claim are (1) If $m$ or $n$ is even, such a coloring exists and (2) If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, such a coloring does not exist. Proving (1) is tricky (you have to find a coloring) but proving (2) should be easy.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't see how that's clear from the question. Nowhere is it implied that the union of the two subgraphs is the whole graph. I don't think the question makes any sense, which is perhaps why the asker hasn't offered any thoughts or attempts.

Comment: I interpreted the question as "for all edges $e$, there exist two subgraphs such that...". Perhaps what it means is "There exist two subgraphs such that for all edges $e$..."

Comment: @NoName I agree that the question is rather ambiguous, but "There exist two isomorphic subgraphs such that each edge $e$ is in exactly one" (equivalently, my coloring formulation) is the only version that holds iff $mn$ is even, and isn't trivial. (With the quantifiers in the other order, you can just take one subgraph to only consist of $e$, and the other subgraph to be any other edge.)

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov. It all makes sense now, I will look into this question again and try to post a solution. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If m or n is even => Every edge of $K_{m,n}$ is in 1 of the 2 isomorphic subgraphs of $K_{m,n}$

1. If 2|m, then there exists a subgraph $K_{m/2, n}$ by picking m/2
   vertices that incident with all the n vertices. The remaining m/2
   vertices also  construct a
   subgraph $K_{m/2, n}$. These 2 subgraphs are isomorphic.
2. If 2|n, it is the same reason as above, a $K_{m, n}$ can be divided into two $K_{m, n/2}$ subgraphs, and they are isomorphic

If every edge of $K_{m,n}$ is in 1 of the 2 isomorphic subgraphs of $K_{m,n}$ => m or n is even.

1. For a contradiction, assume $m$ and $n$ are both odd. for $K_{m,n}$ has total $ mn $ odd number of edges.
2. According to the definition of isomorphism, these two isomorphic subgraphs must have an equal number of edges. Therefore, the sum of their edges, which is equal to $ mn $, must be even.
3. $ mn $ cannot be even and odd. (prove by contradiction)

Therefore, every edge of a bipartite complete graph $K_{m,n}$ is contained in exactly one of two isomorphic subgraphs of $K_{m,n}$ if and only if m or n is even.